# Xcode 6.1 - ObjC/Swift Codebase, Bridging Header and Code Completion

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

so I'm attempting to add some Swift classes to my existing ObjC codebase. However, now I'm running into a weird issue:

I created my `ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h` and have been importing my ObjC header files as I need them in my new `.swift` files. I have a nested `.xcodeproj` inside my project and upon attempting to expose a class from that nested project to Swift via my bridging header, Xcode stops auto-completion.

Funny thing is, I can still run the app without problems:

```
let myObj = Object()
println(myObj) //returns <Object: 0x7abde160>
```

when typing `myObj` Xcode auto-complete shows me `<<error type>>`. I have tried the common suggestions, removing `ModuleCache` folder and all.. Nothing helped.

Anybody experience the same issue ?

Comment: I have had this problem but don't recall what I did to fix it. I wonder if the order of the .h files in your bridging header has something to do with it.

Comment: @MikeTaverne just tried, no luck.. I managed to get code-completion to work by doing '#import <subproj/Object.h>' -- however that gives me "duplicate interface definition" errors at build time :(